# FFT; Why is the frequency bin resolution dependent on Time?

Tags: performance, transform, fft, frequency, bin

I'm looking into Fast Fourier TRansform (FFT) to create a discrete Fourier transform (DFT) of a part of a song.

I found https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEwIjyOKFQ4 and http://www.bitweenie.com/listings/fft-zero-padding/ to be especially helpful to answer most of my questions.

Still I'm left with one question. Why is the frequency bin size dependent on time? Is this an property of the FFT-algorithm? Or is it not possible to see the difference between the frequencies in one bin?

Comment: this question is better suited for [DSP StackExchange](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/). There it can get better attention.

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://dsp.stackexchange.com ? But ultimately it boils down to the Uncertainty Principle - see: http://www.thephysicsmill.com/2013/01/13/resolution-fourier-analysis-and-the-heisenberg-uncertainty-principle/